# Shortened url redirect?

Tags: php, url

I need help to get this done.

My webpages have formatted urls in this pattern: "http://qifu.us/index.php?page=item&id=4" for example - if there are more pages, only the last page id number will be different.

I want to get this part "index.php?page=item&id=" out, and shortened like "http://qifu.us/s4",  when a user input the shortened url into to address bar, it will be directed to the right page, which is the true url.

I am thinking to save the STATIC part "index.php?page=item&id=" into a string variable, and append the DYNAMIC page id - which is 4 in this example, then use Javascript or PHP to direct to the right page. But I don't know how the steps, pls help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually an htaccess will be very good for this purpose.

For urls like `http://qifu.us/s4` do the following: Create a file with name `.htaccess` and place at your root directory with the following content.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^s([^/]*)$ /index.php?page=item&id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't work for me. I've made a .htaccess, copy and pasted exactly the same code and uploaded to the server, it reports the 500 error: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: Still 500 Internal server error for the url "http://qifu.us/s4" redirect, but if you try "http://qifu.us/index.php?page=item&id=4" it works.

Comment: It worked now, and I think Apache needs few time to updating. Big thanks.